# UISearchController does not get released from memory when Active

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have a `UISearchController` in my application which is active. Now the ParentController which is showing the search controller gets popped from button action inside the controller.

Now what is happening is that the due to this search controller, the parent controller is not getting released from the memory. Any suggestions how to handle this scenario

I have to set `self.searchController.active = false;` everytime i have to pop.

Comment: You might consider implementing dealloc/deInit in your parentController and remove the search controller view. There is an open radar for UISearchController weird issue which might be related to your problem : http://www.openradar.me/22250107

Comment: How do you have the UISearchController defined?

Answer (score 0):

Usual scenario is where a child VC has an unneeded reference to the parent and does not specify this to be weak. Therefore, a retain cycle appears where the parent retains the child and the child retains the parent so none of them are actually released.

This might be your case as well.